# $\text{tr}\log(A)+\text{tr}\log(B)$ for complex matrices?

Tags: matrices

For positive definite matrices $A$ and $B$, we have the following identity
$$\text{tr}\log(A)+\text{tr}\log(B)=\text{tr}\log(AB).$$

What can be said about the case for complex matrices $A$ and $B$? Assume they are still invertible.

Comment: Does $\log(zw)=\log z+\log w$ hold for nonzero complex numbers $z,w$? In particular, what *is* $\log z$?

Comment: I see, does the problem occur when taking the product of $z$ and $w$ sends you to a number that crosses the negative real axis?

Comment: What do you mean by "crosses"? Certainly if $zw$ lands on the negative real axis, you have a problem. But even if it does not, you can still have problems.

Comment: What I meant was if $w$ and $z$ are on the same branch, $zw$ might be on a different branch?

Comment: Might there be a simplification if $B=A^{\dagger}$?

Comment: Yes, that's precisely the problem with the case of numbers. How are you defining $\log A$ for an invertible matrix $A$? Even if it is diagonalizable, you're going to run into the branch problem we've been discussing, aren't you?

Comment: Would you have to assume the eigenvalues all lie on the same branch? Or at least make some choice. In the case of $B=A^{\dagger}$, as long as $A$ does not have real non-positive eigenvalues there doesn't seem to be any branch issues.

Comment: But you still have the crossing issues, don't you, if you allow general eigenvalues?

Comment: You're right, I think I would need to further assume $A$ is normal. Then the product of the eigenvalues $\lambda$ and $\lambda ^*$ will always avoid "crossing".

Comment: No, that's not right. The eigenvalues of a unitary matrix (which is certainly normal) are complex numbers of modulus $1$.

Comment: To be specific, what do you do if $\lambda = -1$? Then you won't have a log.

Comment: Right, so $A$ would have to be normal, with no real non-positive eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If matrix logarithm is defined as a primary matrix function and the principal branch of logarithm is selected, the trace identity is still valid when all eigenvalues of $A,B$ and $AB$ are positive (we don't need $A$ or $B$ to be positive definite). This is because $\operatorname{tr}\log(M)=\log(\det(M))$ when $M$ has a positive spectrum.

If matrix logarithm is defined as a primary matrix function but at least one of $A,B$ or $AB$ has a non-positive eigenvalue, it can happen that the trace identity **always** fails regardless of the branch of logarithm selected. For example, let $\omega=\exp(2\pi i/3),\,A=\operatorname{diag}(1,\omega,\omega^2)$ and $B=\omega I_3$. Then $AB=\operatorname{diag}(\omega,\omega^2,1)$ and
\begin{aligned}
\log(A)&=\operatorname{diag}\left(\log(1),\log(\omega),\log(\omega^2)\right),\\
\log(B)&=\operatorname{diag}\left(\log(\omega),\log(\omega),\log(\omega)\right),\\
\log(AB)&=\operatorname{diag}\left(\log(\omega),\log(\omega^2),\log(1)\right).
\end{aligned}
Hence
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{tr}\log(AB)
&=\log(1)+\log(\omega)+\log(\omega^2)\\
&\ne\log(1)+4\log(\omega)+\log(\omega^2)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\log(A)+\operatorname{tr}\log(B),
\end{aligned}
because $\log(\omega)$ is nonzero for all branches of logarithm.